# RXJS - Under the hood how is it implemented to remove old values?

Tags: angular, rxjs

Basically have an infinite stream of values being generated from some "source" in realtime.

I'm new to RXJS but each "request" subscribes to this source, and i'm wondering if there's a potential memory leak here as each item is pushed onto source with `.next` the source itself is a `ReplaySubject` under the hood wont RXJS be pushing these into some infinitely growing collection? (array or object)? how do i clean up this collection with "stale" values?

I.E Maybe i want to remove from my "ReplaySubject" values that have existed for more than 2hrs but from the under the hood collection

Code looks something like this...

```
const Stream = new ReplaySubject();

(async () => {
    await InfiniteSource.connect();
    InfiniteSource.each((message) => next(message))
})()


// Somewhere else.
Stream.subscribe((value) => // uses the value); // my requests
```

Comment: Here is the source code, pretty simple extension of a subject. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts

Comment: Wanted to avoid reading through all the inheritance to figure out if there's any 'cleanup' process being run in the underlying collection storing the values produced by `.next`

Comment: As you can see from [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/ReplaySubject.ts#L50-L51), you can control the size of the internal buffer and how long the values should be stored.